# How to add JSON field in DB?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have some JSON field type in DB (manually added):

```
{"0": "ROLE_USER"}
```

The model of User:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="json")
 */
private $roles = [];
```

The Controller:

```
$user->setRoles(array('{"0": "ROLE_USER"}'));
```

It works adding data to DB:

```
["{\"0\": \"ROLE_USER\"}"]
```

If I add it with no array - there is an error:

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\User::setRoles()
must be of the type array, string given
```

**What should I do to have exactly `{"0": "ROLE_USER"}` in DB?**

Comment: You don't want to store such serialized datas in your DB. Think about normalization

Comment: `json_decode()` will do the job

Comment: @Cid Thank you for your answer. It doesn't :( Error was returned: Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\User::setRoles() must be of the type array, object given

Comment: @Cid It is definitely works with json_decode: [{"0": "ROLE_USER"}] if I use it with array. However I don't need this array here just pure JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
$user->setRoles(array('{"0": "ROLE_USER"}'));
```

To

```
$user->setRoles(["ROLE_USER"]);
```

That will do the job.

---

Your array declaration is wrong. You push ONE Item to the array and the item is: `{"0": "ROLE_USER"}` as a plain string.

For a doctrine "json" column you dont need to json_encode or json_decode yourself. Doctrine will handle that for you!

The Flow:
**1)** You give Doctrine a array
**2)** Doctrine will json_encode your array and save it in the column as json_data
**3)** If you request the column value, doctrine will json_decode your array so you can work with your array again.

---

Your desired goal is also not correct.
You want json_data like this:

```
{"0": "ROLE_USER"}
```

But i think you will have data like this:

```
{"ROLE_USER"}
```

But both cases would leed to the same array:

```
array {
  0 => ROLE_USER  
}
```

Comment: I have ["ROLE_ADMIN"] in DB and it works. Looks like my approach with Roles was incorrect. Thank you that have helped me to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Doctrine as ORM, you should use existing `json` mapping type that stores array as JSON string and automatically (de)serialize data.

Comment: Thank you for your support!

Comment: notice: `json_array` is deprecated since 2.6, you should use `json` instead.